# Using Vector array variable in functions C++

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I want to save the data from the variable `name` in the code below to my output file `data.txt` seems easy enough?

Nope, since I am scanning the root `"."` dir of the `.exe` for files and then outputting them into `cmd` easy enough, Why am I struggling to simply output to a file as well?

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718601/c-how-do-i-use-variables-from-one-function-to-another) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492228/c-function-output) link. They helped a bit.

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated.

Original virgin [code](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/189681/)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> get_filenames(std::experimental::filesystem::path path)
{
    namespace stdfs = std::experimental::filesystem;
    std::vector<std::string> filenames;
    const stdfs::directory_iterator end{};
    for (stdfs::directory_iterator iter{ path }; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        if (stdfs::is_regular_file(*iter)) 
            filenames.push_back(iter->path().string());
    }
    return filenames;
}



void Dirloop(){
    for (const auto& name : get_filenames(".")) std::cout << name << '\n';
}


void Outfile() {

    std::ofstream outputFile("data.txt", std::ios::out);
    outputFile << name << std::endl;
    outputFile.close();
    cout << "Generated data.txt!\n";
}

int main()
{
    Dirloop();
    Outfile();
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `outputFile << name << std::endl;` From where comes `name`? It's hard to make suggestions about fixing code that is clearly impossible.

Comment: You declare `name` in the `DirLoop` function, but you're trying to use it in `Outfile`.

Comment: Change `Outfile` so it takes `name` as a parameter, and call it from `Dirloop`. It also should open the file in `std::ios::app` mode so that it adds to the file each time instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `get_filenames` in `main()`. Then you can pass the vector as an argument to both `Dirloop()` and `Outfile()`.

```
void Dirloop(const std::vector<std::string> &filenames){
    for (const auto& name : filenames) {
        std::cout << name << '\n';
    }
}


void Outfile(const std::vector<std::string> &filenames) {

    std::ofstream outputFile("data.txt", std::ios::out);
    for (const auto& name : filenames) {
        outputFile << name << '\n';
    }
    outputFile.close();
    cout << "Generated data.txt!\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> filenames = get_filenames(".");
    Dirloop(filenames);
    Outfile(filenames);
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the error error:  C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from... in VC 2015 any ideas? I'm thinking its a conversion character missing?

Comment: Typo, `get_filenames` should have been `get_filenames()`